# Where are the Graphics Card settings?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hardware

I can´t seem to find the Graphics Card settings under preferences/system. Is this just about the current blender version?

Comment: You can accidentally disable Cycles in add-ons, which you can check by going to add-ons searching for cycles; but if you do that the Cycles Render Devices tab should be there, only empty.   Which version of Blender are you using? 'current' can be confusing to people when there are LTS releases.

Comment: I am using Version 2.93.5. The Cycles Add-on is activated. Is the tab supposed to be there in Add-ons?

Comment: Weird.  In 2.93.5 the tab should be in System as  james_t wrote in their answer.  If you've disabled it in add-ons, then in System 'Cycles Render Devices' should appear but there should be a blank panel underneath it.  I don't know how to get into the state you're in.

Comment: @MartyFouts -- any chance that some Read-Only folder problem might be causing this?

Comment: @james_t I can't think of how, but I suppose it's possible. There are a bunch of bug reports for similar problems, but they're all marked resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The only setting are in the System Tab in Settings:

[image]

Comment: The Cycles Render Devices tab is missing in the current display of Settings in blender.